# Preventing code to run multiple times in action

Tags: ember.js

I have code in action that works fine if the person clicks only a single time on the button however if they click multiple time fast on the button, that code get run many times and creating weird issues.  Anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the `disabled` attribute of your `<button>`/`<a>` to prevent users from triggering it again while you are processing the first action. To do so, I typically use a flag to determine if that action is currently processing. If the flag is set, set the `disabled` attribute. It's also a good idea to have a guard statement in your action as well. As some browsers may not respect the `disabled` attribute.

Controller/Component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isLoading: false,
    actions: {
       yourAction() {
           // It's a good idea to use a guard statement here as well. Just incase the browser doesn't respect the `disabled` attribute.
           if(this.get('isLoading')) {
               return;
           }
           this.set('isLoading', true);
           // Do your work here. If it's a promise, use `finally` to unset the flag to avoid forever loading on errors.
           this.set('isLoading', false);
       }
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<button {{action 'yourAction'}}
        disabled={{isLoading}}>
    Your Action
</button>
```

Using this method, you can also add some loading styling on your action as well. Perhaps a spinner as pseudo element:

Template:

```
<button class="{{if isLoading 'loading'}}"
        {{action 'yourAction'}}
        disabled={{isLoading}}>
    Your Action
</button>
```

**Edit**
As ykaragol [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339300/1174287), if you want/can add a library to your Ember app, [`ember-concurrency`](https://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/introduction) will greatly simplify the native Ember example above. They have a guide [here](https://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs/tutorial/refactor) which refactors the example above into a more readable example using `ember-concurrency`.

Answer (score 2):

First solution is *disabling the button after clicked by setting the `disabled` property of the button*.

Although setting `disabled` property of the button can completely solve the solution; spreading the *re-enable* logic to the code is not nice, when some async operation is being executed.

Further more, re-enabling the button can be more complex when you have some other conditions to disable the button. (e.g. If a field on the form has an invalid value, you may again want to disable the button.)

We mostly prefer [`ember-concurrency`](https://ember-concurrency.com) addon for such needs. Its  `task` structure provides a more readable code for most cases.

Comment: I tried using ember-concurrency it does not seem to fix the problem. Basically I have a logic that based on a counter when you click on a button its increments the counter by 1 and what happens its essentially if you click pretty fast you end its increments by 2 and its mess up my logic. so I am trying to lock that variables I guess that no mather how many times you click it will increment 1 times

Comment: then does `disabling` help you? If you provide twiddle I can look further.

Comment: No I that was my first solution and I still able to reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your button.

```
 onclick="this.disabled=true;"
```

Example:

```
 <button onclick="this.disabled=true;">Click</button>
```

When you click the button, the onclick runs immediately and disables the button to prevent additional clicks.